# can multiple click events be used on the same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#button1").click(function(e)
{
//action
});
$("#button2").click(function(e)
{
 //do something
    $("#button1").click(function(f)
    {
    //do something else
    });
});
```

I have two buttons doing different actions.but if button 2 is clicked,i need button 1 to do a different task on the next click without the first function being executed.
any suggestions?

Comment: why not just do it in click of button 2 why need to bind to button when you need to click button 2 in the first place?

Comment: Use `unbind("click").click` in the event defined in `$("#button2")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that ,you need to use one variable scope for detect whether button 1 or 2 is click

```
var btn = 1; // default
$("#button1").click(function(e)
{
  if(btn){
    #button1 click
  }
  else{
    #after button2 click
  }
});
$("#button2").click(function(e)
{
    btn = 2; //change value after button2 click 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into jQuery's .on() and .off() capabilities.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

As it says in the 'off' link above, you can create namespaces for your click events, so you can add and remove just the particular on and off events you like. Something like this:

```
$("#button1").on("click.myName", function(e){
        //action
});

$("#button2").click(function(e){
    //do something

    $("#button1").off("click.myName").on("click.myOtherName", function(e) {
        //do something else
    });

});
```

This allows you to target your click events more directly, and not call `.off()` generically, wiping out all click events.

Answer (score 0):

One method you could use is by unbinding any event listener before adding a new event listener to the button you want to change.

This can be done with the on() and off() functions in Jquery.

```
$("#button1").off('click').on('click',function(e)
{
    //action
});
```

You can then do the same thing with button 2...

```
$("#button2").off('click').on('click',function(e)
{
    //action
    $("#button1").off('click').on('click',function(e)
    {
        //action
    });
});
```

By doing this, the last on click that you set is the only one that will occur when you click that element.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this once

```
$("#button1").click(function(e)
{
//action
});
$("#button2").click(function(e)
{
 //do something
  $("#button1").unbind();
  $("#button1").bind('click', function(f)
   {
     //do something else
   });
});
```

I hope this would work for you.